# Check if a point is inside an arbitrary box

Tags: javascript, python

I recently got the below from an interview questions and I am not able to solve them.

*Implement the `function bool IsInside(Point[] boxCorners, Point p)` that returns `true` if point `P` is inside an arbitrarily rotated box.*

*You can assume the box corners are anticlockwise, so you can think of it as*

- boxCorner[0] – Top left
- boxCorner[1] - Bottom Left
- boxCorner[2]- bottom right
- boxCorner[3]- Top Right*

I want to know how I can solve the above in javascript or python

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

function isInside(boxCorners, p) {
    
}
```

Comment: Provide proper input and respective output.

Comment: Draw an imaginary vertical or horizontal line through the point and count the intersections with the edges of the box. The point is in the box if there are two intersections and the point is between them.

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54301/determine-whether-or-not-a-point-lies-within-a-rotated-rectangle

Comment: Here you can find some algorithms to solve the problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon. Then you can look for specific implementations in the language you want (e.g. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ray-casting_algorithm#JavaScript)

Comment: @Reyno  Let's check the box [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1] and [1, 0] and the point [0.1, 0.1]. It's not in box but your approach returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can then use the [raycasting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm) to have the answer. This is basically the following:

- From the point you want to test, draw a vertical line that goes toward the bottom.
- Check how many lines of the polygon intersects the line
- If there are an odd number of them, it means you point is inside